# Issue in Object creation concurrently in java web

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces, jboss

I have developed maven web project using spring primefaces  and run on jboss 5.0 server.
The Application is cloud based and multiple users can access concurrently.
My issue is when create objects concurrently sometimes refer previous object.this is ok with sequentially. But, when called same method in parallel it run as ambiguous way. Is it issue in primefaces?

```
depositController method:
@ManagedBean(name = "depositController")
@ViewScoped
public class DepositController {
public void depositAcc(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    try {            
        validate = true;
        TrxnObj tempTrxnObj = trxnObj;
        if (requiredFieldValidate()) {
            this.mobileNoVerify();
            if (validate) {
                this.amountValidate();
            }
        } else {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            message.setSummary("Please Enter the Required Fields");
            context.addMessage("ad", message);
            return;
        }
        if (!validate) {
            return;
        }

        if (isRCP) {
            if (null == userManager) {
                userManager = (UserManager) SpringUtil.getApplicationContext().getBean("userManager");
            }                
            merchant = userManager.getMerchantDetails(AppConstants.TRXN_CODE_WALLET_CASH_IN_WEB, merchantID);

            if (null == commonManager) {
                commonManager = (CommonManager) SpringUtil.getApplicationContext().getBean("commonManager");
            }
            //insert txn id
            WSRequest request = new WSRequest();
            request.setMerchantId(merchantID);
            request.setMerchantOutletCode(merchantOutletCode);
            request.setCustomerMobileNumber(tempTrxnObj.getMobileNo());
            request.setMobileNumber(merchant.getMobileNumber());
            request.setPinCode(merchant.getPinCode());
            request.setTransactionAmount(tempTrxnObj.getAmount().doubleValue());
            if(branchCode!=null && !branchCode.equals("")){
                request.setUserName(userId+"-"+branchCode);
            }else{
                request.setUserName(userId);
            }
            if (tempTrxnObj.getNote() == null || tempTrxnObj.getNote().isEmpty()) {
                request.setNote("Cash In at " + merchantID + " for " + tempTrxnObj.getMobileNo());
            } else {
                request.setNote(tempTrxnObj.getNote());
            }
            request.setMerchantTransactionId(getRCPTransactionRef());

            CashInRequest cashInRequest = new CashInRequest();
            cashInRequest.setWsRequest(request);
            CashInResponse cashInResponse = commonManager.callCashInService(cashInRequest);

            if (cashInResponse.getWsResponse().getResponseCode() == AppConstants.WS_TRXN_WEB_RES_SUCCESS) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("ad", new FacesMessage("Transaction Success: " + cashInResponse.getWsResponse().getResponse()));
                receiptObj.setValues(this.trxnObj, locationShortCode, customerName);
                recieptPrintEnabled = true;
                receiptObj.setRefNumber(cashInResponse.getWsResponse().getReference());
                receiptObj.setCusName(userControlObj.getMwtUserWalletDetails().getName());
                receiptObj.setUtilityType("CASH IN");
                receiptObj.setAccountNumber(userControlObj.getMwtUserWallet().getMobileNo());
                receiptObj.setNote("Accepted payment for CASH IN.Thank You.");
                reset();
            } else {

                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
                message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                message.setSummary("Transaction Failed");
                context.addMessage("ad", message);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e,e)
    }   
}
```

DepositAcc.xhtml:

```
            <p:messages id="msgs" for="ad" globalOnly="true"/>

            <h:panelGrid columns="9" cellpadding="5" id="add_edit" styleClass="add-form">   

                <h:outputLabel for="mobileNo" value="*Confirm Mobile No:"/> 
                <p:inputText id="mobileNo" value="#{depositController.mobileNoCnfrm}" required="true" disabled="#{depositController.trxnObj.mobileNo == null}">
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="mobileNo" display="icon"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="amount" value="*Deposit Amount:"/> 
                <p:inputText id="amount" value="#{depositController.trxnObj.amount}" onkeyup="$(this).val(addCommas($(this).val()))" required="true" disabled="#{depositController.trxnObj.mobileNo == null}">                                                   
                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"
                                     groupingUsed="true"                                                                                
                                     pattern="#,##0.00"/>
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="amount" display="icon"/> 

                <h:outputLabel for="amountCnfrm" value="*Confirm Amount:"/> 
                <p:inputText id="amountCnfrm" value="#{depositController.amountCnfrm}" onkeyup="$(this).val(addCommas($(this).val()))" required="true" disabled="#{depositController.trxnObj.mobileNo == null}">                                                   
                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"
                                     groupingUsed="true"                                                                                
                                     pattern="#,##0.00"/>
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="amountCnfrm" display="icon"/>      

                <h:outputLabel for="location" value="*Branch Location:" rendered="#{!depositController.isRCP}"/> 
                <p:inputText id="location" value="#{depositController.location}" required="true" disabled="true" style="width: 200px" rendered="#{!depositController.isRCP}">                                                   
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="location" display="icon" rendered="#{!depositController.isRCP}"/>                     

                <h:outputLabel for="note" value="Note:"/>
                <p:inputTextarea id="note" value="#{depositController.trxnObj.note}" disabled="#{depositController.trxnObj.mobileNo == null}"
                                 rows="4" cols="20" counter="counter" maxlength="100"       
                                 counterTemplate="({0}/100)">
                </p:inputTextarea>
                <h:outputText id="counter"/>
                <p:message for="note" display="icon"/>

            </h:panelGrid>  


            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" id="btns" styleClass="add-btn">                    

                <p:commandButton value="Deposit" ajax="true" update=":add:addFields :add:btns :list :dialog" actionListener="#{depositController.depositAcc}" 
                                 disabled="#{!depositController.depositEnable}"/>

                <p:commandButton value="Reset" update="addFields btns" process="@this" 
                                 disabled="#{!depositController.depositEnable}"
                                 actionListener="#{depositController.reset}"/>

                <p:commandButton value="View Receipt" onclick="dlg.show()" 
                                 disabled="#{!depositController.recieptPrintEnabled}"/>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:fieldset>

    </h:form>
```

Comment: Which objects refer to previous objects? Where exactly do you have problems in that code?

Comment: Where does trxnObj come from? Is it a class level field? If so, why? Of course you can have then concurrency issues.

Comment: Im doing load testing and execute depositAcc() method 100 times concurrently by setting different values to  trxnObj. Ex: trxnObj has parameter called amount. so i set values 100,101,102.. to 199 as amount and execute. but when i print trxnObj some time it missing 105 and print 104 twice.

Comment: yeah, trxnObj is class level variable. But end of the method i have reset the object.  this.trxnObj = new TrxnObj();

Comment: Please take good care of tagging your questions. How is this maven related? Does it work if you create the app manually without maven? And how is it jboss related? Does it work on tomcat or tomee? And how is this PrimeFaces related? Does it work if you use plain jsf components instead of the PrimeFaces ones? And why not tag the question with spring then?